# Maintain versions of a tree

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a tree datastructure having upto 1000 nodes at a particular level ( max depth of 8-9 levels).

I need to maintain **versions** of this entire tree. A version is created after some processing happens. Between these versions, the data in the nodes may change ( not more than a 100 or so).

As of now, I was cloning the entire tree for each new version, but the space consumption is huge after a few versions. I **cannot entirely** delete the previous version records since I need to keep a track of the changes.

Whats the optimal way to store these versions in the database? (If not the db, any alternative way).

Comment: Difficult to answer without more information. Is the structure of the tree important or is it just a means to get fast access to the nodes? Do the keys change?

Comment: trees and versions... that smells to immutable data structures.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a very straightforward problem, but it is a solved problem. In general, data structures that remember their history are called [persistent data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure).

The linked Wikipedia page has [an example of a persistent tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Trees) that you should look at.

The [path copying approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Path_Copying) is fairly simple to implement but doesn't have performance as good as is possible.

Comment: For reference, the MIT CSAIL website has recordings of Erik Demaine lecturing on the various advanced data structures, http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/spring12/lectures/. He describes persistent data structures in the first lecture.

Comment: from the wiki link, it seems my use case matches with the Partially persistent datastructures. But i cannot imagine as to how they will solve the space complexity issue for me

Comment: @user2558642 You won't have to imagine how they solve the space complexity problem.  The Wikipedia page describes a surprisingly good space complexity for the path copying + fat node mixture.

Comment: I believe the path copying approach is only applicable for binary trees and not for m-Trees (trees with arbitrary no. of children nodes). Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @user2558642 Path copying works fine with k-ary trees.  What about it makes you think it might not work?

Comment: I am basically storing the tree in my db by having a parent column as a FK for the nodes. Since during path copying, a node may have an indegree > 1 ( more than 1 parent), i'd have to create a seperate record for this relation, basically killing the benefit of the technique

Comment: @user2558642 You want to store the list of children, not the parent. Your NODE table should have column ID and then other data columns, and your EDGE table should have column PARENT_ID and CHILD_ID, where both combined is the primary key. If node 3 has 4 children, { 4, 7, 8, 9 }, then the EDGE table should contain (3,4),(3,7),(3,8),(3,9).

Answer (score 0):

Keep each unique node permanently frozen in one table (once you insert a node in there, never edit or delete it). If you need to change a node even slightly, insert this modified node in your table. Then, keep track of your tree versions with foreign keys to the node table. That should require a trivial amount of space per tree.

Answer (score 0):

Store each "version" as a map between the nodes that are changed and the old/new values.

You can reconstruct any previous version by inverting the sequence of operations.

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines. Here I do not need to reconstruct the previous version, simply display a history of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

a possible practical solution might be:

if you need to restore an old version:

1. serialize the new tree and the previous tree into XML.
2. diff the new XML with the previous XML, serialize and store the difference in a database
   (for a Java solution I found http://diffxml.sourceforge.net and  XMLUnit, but it
   has to be checked if they are able to compute the difference between the new XML
   and the previous XML in a way which permits to restore easily the previous XML from
   the new XML).
3. each time an old version is needed, one successively takes the differences from the
   database, from the most recent to the most remote, and applies them in this order to
   the (serialized into XML) current tree, to get to the XML form of the old version of the tree.

if you do not need  to reconstruct the old version, then simply use XMLUnit to compute 
the differences and store their serializations in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you care about previous versions of the tree and space is your primary concern, assuming  that from one version to the other the treas are not entirely different you can store only the difference between the treas. How to do that is entirely up to you:
 - you can do an in/pre/post order parsing of the tree (assuming it's binary) and come up with a logic to get from the location of on difference to the other
  -or use a linked list to store only the differences + some logic to rebuild the treas